# How to run a process using nginx

Tags: git, shell, nginx, command-line, bitbucket

I'm looking for a way to configure nginx such that it will run a command line process with a given url.

The idea is to have a process to pull the latest version from git for a site if the repository is updated.

Getting bitbucket to call a url on an update is easy enough.
Not sure yet on how to action a command line process from nginx.

What would be the easiest way of doing this?

Found an answer here. [nginx - How to run a shell script on every request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891148/nginx-how-to-run-a-shell-script-on-every-request)

The main difference between this question and the other question is I was not thinking 'shell' when I asked myself the question. I think in terms of processes. When I searched for process virtually nothing came up. I only found answers when I substituted 'shell' for 'process'. A subtle difference but a difference that will save someone some time in the future

Had a follow on issue with fcgiwrap on Ubuntu 12.04 which was resolved after reading [CGI reply error on nginx server using fcgiwrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106224/cgi-reply-error-on-nginx-server-using-fcgiwrap)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx - How to run a shell script on every request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891148/nginx-how-to-run-a-shell-script-on-every-request)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the answer you mentioned in your question but you can also add and use any script which can pull changes from git every X seconds.

Your code will be updated on every pull and there were no changes nothing will happen.

your script will look something like:

```
while [ 1 ] ; do git pull ... ; sleep X; done;
```

This line will run forever until you stop it.
You can start it via script, use watchdog or crontab, whaever you fill more comfortable with.

Comment: A reasonable idea that I might fall back to. I prefer event processing rather than poll processing.